# Не находит в req.body ничего

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

Должен вывести `search`, а выводит пустой объект

```html
<form className="header__search-form" action="/products" method="POST">
      <span>Поиск</span>
      <input type="text" className="header-search-input" name="search" />
</form>
```

```js
app.post('/products', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body); // {}
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
})
```

Comment: body-parser стоит? на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` настроен (если просто сабмитишь форму)? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229759

Comment: точно, забыл добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Устанавливаешь body-parser:

```bsh
$ npm i body-parser
```

И подключаешь его:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

---

Если данные формы будут отправляться как `multipart/form-data`, например, при передаче файлов, - тогда потребуется подключение библиотеки [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Подробнее это описано вот в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215091).

Comment: плз, галкой пометь ответ принятым